# Javascript scope issue: function available in $(doc).ready(), but not in event handler

Tags: javascript, jquery, scope

I am using a [3rd party script](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/powerzoomer.htm) to add a zoom function to images on a page. This works quite well with static, but not with dynamic content.

*Static version, works:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#gallery_main_img').addpowerzoom();
})
```

*Dynamic version, doesn't work:*

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
    $('#gallery_main_img').load(OnGalleryImageChanged);
})

function OnGalleryImageChanged() {
    $('#gallery_main_img').addpowerzoom();
}
```

The *addpowerzoom* function is created with this code in the PowerZoom script, which is referenced in the `<head>` of my page:

```
$.fn.addpowerzoom=function(options){ 
    // function content here
}
```

When entering the event handler, Firebug gives me this error message:
`$("#gallery_main_img").addpowerzoom is not a function.`

So it seems to be a scope problem. My question is:

**How do I access the addpowerzoom() function from within my event handler?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you check that [3rd party script's source](http://www.dynamicdrive.com/dynamicindex4/ddpowerzoomer.js), the first thing you'll notice it do is set jQuery in [noConflict mode](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.noConflict/), with the code `jQuery.noConflict()` and it doesn't assign it to a variable either, meaning the `$` isn't reserved for jQuery anymore.

As you mentioned that the first case is working, I am presuming that you have the ready statement before you include the 3rd party script, because otherwise that wouldn't work either.

You could either change your code to this (replacing `$` with `jQuery`):

```
jQuery(document).ready(function(){ 
    jQuery('#gallery_main_img').load(OnGalleryImageChanged);
})

function OnGalleryImageChanged() {
    jQuery('#gallery_main_img').addpowerzoom();
}
```

example: http://jsfiddle.net/niklasvh/8Vjnu/

or wrap the code inside of a:

```
(function($) { 
  $(function() {
    // more code using $ as alias to jQuery
  });
})(jQuery);
```

or perhaps remove the `noConflict` from the 3rd party script altogether (something that the author should have never put in there in the first place, unless they assume that everyone who use the script wants to remove `jQuery` from `$`).

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help! I ended up throwing out the `noConflict` call, which required some more fiddling with the script to get it running again, but now it works as expected.

Comment: @Treb  Yes, that would be the best solution, presuming you wish to use jQuery normally elsewhere as well. Glad you got it working :)